# JCR-SQL2 Query Wildcard search not working.

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr, jcr-sql2

I want to run this JCR SQL2 query:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE path LIKE '/A/B/%'
```

But after running the query I am getting the following Exception:

```
javax.jcr.query.InvalidQueryException: Query:
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE jcr:(*)path LIKE '/A/B/%'; expected: (, ., =, <>, <, >, <=,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/A/B/%])
```

Read more [here](http://www.h2database.com/jcr/grammar.html)

Comment: Shouldn't that be ... ISDESCENDANTNODE('/A/B') ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to execute the query:

```
            javax.jcr.query.QueryManager queryManager;

            queryManager = jcrsession.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();
            String expression = "select * from [nt:folder] AS s WHERE ISCHILDNODE(s,'"+name+"')and CONTAINS(s.[edms:owner],'*"+userid+"*')  ORDER BY s.["+Config.EDMS_Sorting_Parameter+"] ASC";

            javax.jcr.query.Query query = queryManager.createQuery(expression, javax.jcr.query.Query.JCR_SQL2);
```